# Cosa vuol dire "per tua regola e norma" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Ferito a morte*, di Raffaele La Capria, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> «Babbo perché guardi me, scusa? Guarda pure dalla parte di Massimo. Lui ha sette anni più di me, è lui che deve dare il buon esempio al fratello minore.» 
>       «Lui per lo meno sta per laurearsi. Tu invece non hai voluto mai studiare.» 
>       «Ma scusa, babbo, pure tu in questo senso, se vogliamo...» 
>       «Io ho cominciato a lavorare a tredici anni, **per tua regola e norma**.»

Non capisco il significato dell'espressione "per tua regola e norma" che appare in questo dialogo. Alla [voce "norma" del vocabolario Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/regola) ho trovato

> *per vostra r*. (più forte, *per vostra norma e r*.), avvisando qualcuno, in tono piuttosto risentito, di ciò che dovrebbe fare, dire o pensare

ma non sono sicura che questo sia il senso dell'espressione che appare nel testo. Il padre sta avvertendo il figlio di quello che dovrebbe pensare?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Il senso è più o meno quello, e in effetti è molto più usuale “per tua norma e regola”. Vedi anche [nel dizionario Hoepli](https://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/R/regola.html), alla fine del punto 1, dove è definito:

> affinché ti possa regolare, detto spec. con tono risentito, per precisare qualcosa che l'interlocutore sembra non aver tenuto nel debito conto

Anche il De Mauro registra l'espressione, sotto la voce [“norma”](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/norma):

> *per tua, vostra norma e regola*, espressione di rimprovero, per lo più ironica, che richiama la persona o le persone cui ci si riferisce a tener conto di un determinato fatto o a comportarsi di conseguenza: *per tua norma e regola, questa casa non è un albergo!*

(e più concisamente anche sotto “regola”).

E questo è appunto il senso in cui è usato qui: il padre precisa in modo risentito qualcosa di cui il figlio non ha tenuto conto, cioè che lui (il padre) non ha lasciato gli studi per svogliatezza ma perché ha cominciato a lavorare da ragazzino.

Comment: Si può aggiungere che questa ripetizione, che rafforza il concetto, è la figura retorica del climax https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Climax_(retorica)

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Non so se arriverei a chiamarlo “climax”, che dovrebbe essere una successione di termini (in genere più di due) sempre più intensi... Forse un'endiadi?

Comment: Ha senso :) Tutto dipende se consideriamo che la norma sia superiore alla regola ;)

Comment: Decisamente “norma e regola”. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tua+norma+e+regola%2Ctua+regola+e+norma&corpus=33&year_end=2019&year_start=1800&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctua%20norma%20e%20regola%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctua%20regola%20e%20norma%3B%2Cc0